# Python: Decorators, scoping and module imports

Tags: python, python-decorators

So I'm trying to learn to use Python (2.x) decorators, and while messing around with them, I encountered ...a weird thing. To summarize, I think I'm trying to use a decorator to add the decorated function to a storage somewhere else.

I don't know if this is the most Pythonic way of doing anything, but I'd like to understand what goes wrong.

Suppose I have a module (that I run as a script) like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# main.py

d = {}
b = []
def mydecorator(name):
    b.append(name)
    def decorator(fun):
        d[name] = fun
        print 'in here', d, b
        return fun
    print 'and here', d, b
    return decorator

class SomeClass:
    @mydecorator('a thing')
    def working_func(self, params):
        # do stuff
        pass

def main():
    # do stuff
    print 'out there', d, b


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints as expected:

```
and here {} ['a thing']
in here {'a thing': <function working_func at 0x7fd6b69e0758>} ['a thing']
out there {'a thing': <function working_func at 0x7fd6b69e0758>} ['a thing']
```

However, if I move the class into a separate module

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# module.py

from main import mydecorator

class AnotherClass:
    @mydecorator('boo')
    def not_workin_func(self, params):
        # do stuff
        pass
```

and import it in `main.py`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# main.py
import module

d = {}
b = []
def mydecorator(name):
    b.append(name)
    def decorator(fun):
        d[name] = fun
        print 'in here', d, b
        return fun
    print 'and here', d, b
    return decorator

def main():
    # do stuff
    print 'out there', d, b


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

changes in the list and dict don't persist:

```
and here {} ['boo']
in here {'boo': <function not_workin_func at 0x7fd1009917d0>} ['boo']
out there {} []
```

I suppose that this has something to do with how python handles scoping / module imports?

Comment: You have a circular import which makes things very difficult to reason through - try moving mydecorator out of `main.py` into either `module.py` or another module.

Comment: Thanks, moving all the decorator stuff into another module works (in the sense that if I then e.g. import `b`, `d` in `main.py`, they do have the same contents as in the first case). So the main problem is the circular import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a circular import, and the dictionary `d` and list `b` get replaced with an empty list after `module` is initialized.

You can see the order of execution by adding some print statements:

module.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# module.py
print('  module - init')

print('  module - importing from main')
from main import mydecorator
#import main


print('  module - definiting class')
class AnotherClass:
    @mydecorator('boo')
    def not_workin_func(self, params):
        # do stuff
        pass
```

main.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# main.py

print('main - importing module')
import module

print('main - making empty d,b')
d = {}
b = []

print('main - definiting mydecorator')
def mydecorator(name):
    b.append(name)
    def decorator(fun):
        d[name] = fun
        print 'in here', d, b
        return fun
    print 'and here', d, b
    return decorator

print('main - defining main')
def main():
    # do stuff
    print 'out there', d, b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('main - running main')
    main()
```

Now when you run `python main.py` you can see what happens in what order:

```
main - importing module
  module - init
  module - importing from main
main - importing module
main - making empty d,b
main - definiting mydecorator
main - defining main
  module - definiting class
and here {} ['boo']
in here {'boo': <function not_workin_func at 0x100ca4aa0>} ['boo']
main - making empty d,b
main - definiting mydecorator
main - defining main
main - running main
out there {} []
```

You can see that `d` and `b` were reassigned to empty lists and dictionaries *after* the decorator was applied in the class definition.

I honestly can't quite figure out how to fix this other than to move the decorator and `d` and `b` out of main and into its own module to resolve the circular dependency, but I think that most people would agree that circular imports should be avoided whenever possible, if not strictly forbidden.